# how to load multiple files into one file using informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I am new to informatics, I have created a mapping that using expression and sorter transformation to load multiple files into one single file which have 2 columns

```
1 data
2 seq number
```

All 10 files have random sequence numbers Like
example:
file1

```
erfef 3
abcdn 1
```

file 2

```
wewewr 4
wderfv 5
```

and so on till 10 files.

Expression transformation code is :

```
INTEGER(LTRIM(RTRIM(seq_num)),TRUE)
```

what I want is to load the file into one big file and sort it according to the seq number.

Got data in output file but number with incorrect seq number.

How to get data in the final table with a correct sequence number.

doing exactly what is mention in the below solution but still getting wrong output. getting output like:

```
erfef 3
abcdn 1                                                                                                                                            
wewewr 4
wderfv 5
```

where as it should be like below:

```
                                                                       where as it should be like 

abcdn 1                                                                                                                                
erfef  3                                                                                                                          
wewewr 4  
wderfv 5
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indirect file load using a list of files to load all files together. Then use sorter on col2 to order the data. Finally use a target file to store data.

Whole mapping should be like this -

```
SQ --> EXP--> SRT(key = col2) --> Target
```

Few things to note -

- In the session, use `indirect file` and use a list file name - mention `filelist1.txt`
- Use `ls -1 file* >filelist1.txt` in pre session command task to create a file list with all required files.
- Expression transformation- convert the col2 to INTEGER if its coming up as string in SQ.
- Sorter transformation- use col2 as key column.

Comment: doing exactly what is mention above but still getting wrong output. getting output like:

Comment: i have to put both column as key otherwise the seq_num value will be 0 for each row

Comment: did your solution worked for you?

Comment: nope it got truncate issue but not able to understand is it due to size or datatype

Comment: make data type to string in source qualifier and source and increase data length to 2000 - and then in EXP convert string to INTEGER. If this also fails pls check if the delimiter in file and informatica are same.

Comment: what about target source and target are same both are flat files

Comment: it doesnt matter - source and target can be files.

Comment: their is some issue in the length of the file . i updated and volla it work fine thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using `indirect` file source is one way.

Another way is to use `command` as source and specify a command that will spit out data from all the files, like `cat file*.csv`.

Just change the `Input Type` to `Command` and provide the command - all this can be set by editing `session -> mapping tab -> Source -> properties`.

Here's an example session:

[image]